# C# .NET core Best way to get current user ID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identity

I have a lot of tables in my database that use a user's identity User.Id as a foreign key. Now, in a lot of the requests I need to do the below lines it seems just in case the User is null (even if I add [Authorise] filter to the function).

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
if (user == null)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorCode = "1201";
    ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "User not found";
    return View("HandledError");
}
var userId = user.Id;
```

Does anyone know the best way I can access this without copying this same code for each function?

I guess I could have a function that retrieves the Id... and throws an exception on Null.. but then I would still need to write it in a try catch everytime anyway....

Any ideas?

Comment: isn't it something like `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`?

Comment: @Hogan, AFAIK there's no 'HttpContext.Current' in Asp.net Core.

Comment: @PoulBak -- probably in web content then.

Answer (score 3):

User id is a claim. You can get it via:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Note: You'll need to add a using for `System.Security.Claims`.

Comment: But is this better than var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
Won't I still need to perform a check to see if userId is null or invalid?

Comment: No. And technically you don't need to with `GetUserAsync` either. If this is behind an authorized endpoint, then the user must exist or they wouldn't be logged in. I suppose it's possible for something like the user to log in and then have their user record deleted following, but that would be weird to say the least. Claims are even more reliable, though, since they're tied to the actual logged in principal. As long as the user is logged in the claims will be set, regardless of what happens at the database-level.

Comment: Hmm, it's just weird that they do this null check in their exemplar applications even if behind an Authorised filter.... Any idea if it still hits the db on a check or is it just reading the clients cookie data?

Comment: Anytime you query a database, it's best practice to assume your query might not match anything. While with this, it's fairly obvious it will return something, it certainly doesn't hurt to be over-cautious. When you access claims on the user principal, however, you are not hitting the database. Those exist in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

In WebApi 2 you can use RequestContext.Principal from within a method on ApiController

```
string id;
id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
id = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();
```